# Print imprime desde corchetes hasta comillas

Tags: python

Cambié de `""` a `''` y lo mismo. Soy algo nuevo

¿Alguna sugerencia?

**Este es mi código**

```
nombre = 'edward'
apellido = 'ortiz'
nombre_completo = nombre + apellido

print("nombre: ",nombre)
print("apellido: ",apellido)
print("nombre completo: ",nombre_completo)
```

Y me está dando el siguiente resultado

```
('nombre', 'edward')
('apellido', 'ortiz')
('nombre completo', 'edwardortiz')
```

Comment: y que error te sale o se supone que debemos adivinar???

Comment: Mi sugerencia es nunca echarle la culpa al editor de código o al lenguaje sin antes haber analizado qué puede estar uno haciendo mal, recuerda que el editor de código realiza las acciones que tú configuraste e indicaste. Esto no quiere decir que los editores no tengan error, por supuesto que los tienen, pero en la mayoría de casos los errores son humanos

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez no manda ningún error es solo que cuando lo ejecuto se supone que solo aparezca el texto   **nombre: Edward** **apellido: Ortiz** **nombre completo: edwardortiz** pero en su lugar como se puede observar en la imagen en el parte de la terminal se imprime todo **('nombre: ', 'edward') a eso me refiero con que aparecen los corchetes y comillas
('apellido: ', 'ortiz')
('nombre comleto: ', 'edwardortiz')**

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán esquema cuando lo ejecuto en otro editor no tengo ese problema yo se que fue algo que le moví, bueno eso creo y en eso es en lo que necesito ayuda.

Comment: bueno mira el codigo que colocaste dice muy poco asumo que es php, ero desconosco que estas haciendo con la terminal... seria interesante que restauraras el visual stufio code a su configuracion ppr defecto y revisa si eso lo corrige

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez es python. si yo creo que si lo voy a restaurar y después comento si se arreglo el problema gracias

Comment: Lo probé en Python y funciona perfecto. ¿Estás seguro de que estás usando Python?

Comment: Confirmo que funciona correctamente. ¿Estás seguro de que ese es tu código y que no estás haciendo nada más?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando Python2.

En Python2, la sentencia `print` no era una función, y por tanto no se ponían paréntesis alrededor de sus "argumentos", porque al no ser una función realmente no lleva argumentos.

La sintaxis era simplemente `print` seguida de las cosas que quisieras imprimir, separadas por comas:

```
print "nombre:", nombre
```

Al ponerle paréntesis alrededor, estás creando una *tupla*, y le estás pidiendo a `print` que **imprima la tupla**, que es exactamente lo que hace cuando muestra `('nombre:', 'edward')`

En Python3 en cambio `print` pasa a ser una función, con lo que los paréntesis sirven para delimitar sus argumentos, y por tanto la sintaxis:

```
print("nombre:", nombre)
```

Ya no crea una tupla, sino que invoca la función `print()` pasándole dos parámetros, por lo que la salida ya será la esperada. **Nota** si quisiéramos imprimirlo como tupla en Python3 habría que poner `print(("nombre:", nombre))`. Los paréntesis interiores crean la tupla que se pasa como (único) parámetro a `print()`.

Ya que Python2 ha dejado de recibir soporte desde hace ya un año y está destinado a desaparecer, te recomiendo que instales Python3 cuanto antes.

Comment: gracias si me sacaste de la duda

Answer (score 0):

este seria tu código original

```
nombre = 'edward'
apellido = 'ortiz'
nombre_completo = nombre + " " +apellido

print("nombre: ",nombre)
print("apellido: ",apellido)
print("nombre completo: ",nombre_completo)
```

te recomiendo probar el siguiente código

```
nombre = 'edward'
apellido = 'ortiz'
nombre_completo = nombre + " " +apellido

print("nombre: "+ nombre)
print("apellido: "+ apellido)
print("nombre completo: " + nombre_completo)
```

la salida de los codigos depende completamente de la consola en la cual se ejecute el codigo. te recomiendo usar Visual Studio Code o Pycharm